# Error in keras - name 'Dense' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, keras

I'm new to Deep Neural Network libraries in python. I've installed Theano & keras in my windows system by following these steps(I already had anaconda):

Install TDM GCC x64.

Run the below code from command prompt

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
conda install mingw libpython
pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git
```

When I'm running the following code in Ipython,

```
import numpy as np
import keras.models
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

it is showing the following error:

---

NameError

Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 1 model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(784,)))

NameError: name 'Dense' is not defined

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9ZMp.png) is the error message screenshot.

How come sequential was imported successfully and 'Dense' was not defined?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need `from keras.layers import Activation, Dense`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem in tensorflow 2.0 and solved it by using

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

Answer (score 0):

For TensorFlow 2.6 you should do this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```